# GetType() and Typeof() in C#

Tags: c#, function, c#-2.0, gettype

```
itemVal = "0";

res = int.TryParse(itemVal, out num);

if ((res == true) && (num.GetType() == typeof(byte)))  
    return true;
else
   return false;  // goes here when I debugging.
```

Why `num.GetType() == typeof(byte)` does not return `true` ?

Comment: its an int not a byte ? why would it return true?

Comment: Yes, Its an int, but I need judge the int is one byte or not. I also implemented some code like `typeof(ushort)`, typeof(ulong).

Comment: I used `typeof(byte)` to define the range of `(num >= 0) && (num <= 255)`

Comment: ``isByte = res&0xff == res`` EDIT: if unsigned, otherwise you will need to check sign bit + the lower bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `num` is an `int`, not a `byte`.

`GetType()` gets the `System.Type` of the object at runtime. In this case, it's the same as `typeof(int)`, since `num` is an `int`.

`typeof()` gets the `System.Type` object of a type at compile-time.

Your comment indicates you're trying to determine if the number fits into a byte or not; the contents of the variable do not affect its type (actually, it's the type of the variable that restricts what its contents can be).

You can check if the number would fit into a byte this way:

```
if ((num >= 0) && (num < 256)) {
    // ...
}
```

Or this way, using a cast:

```
if (unchecked((byte)num) == num) {
    // ...
}
```

It seems your entire code sample could be replaced by the following, however:

```
byte num;
return byte.TryParse(itemVal, num);
```

Comment: That cast goes kaboom in a checked build.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.  It is a build option, Advanced button.

Comment: I believe that is what he meant. In a checked build the compiler will see that the int is being downcast to a byte and there is a possibility of overflow so it throws an exception. Wrapping it in an `unchecked` statement as you did will prevent the conversion check.

Answer (score 2):

Simply because you are comparing a `byte` with an `int`

If you want to know number of bytes try this simple snippet:

```
int i = 123456;
Int64 j = 123456;
byte[] bytesi = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
byte[] bytesj = BitConverter.GetBytes(j);
Console.WriteLine(bytesi.Length);
Console.WriteLine(bytesj.Length);
```

Output:

```
4
8
```

Answer (score 1):

because and int and a byte are different data types.

an int (as it is commonly known) is 4 bytes (32 bits)  an Int64, or Int16 are 64 or 16 bits respectively

a byte is only 8 bits

Answer (score 1):

If **num** is an int it will never return true

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna check if this int value would fit a byte, you might test the following;

```
int num = 0;
byte b = 0;

if (int.TryParse(itemVal, out num) && byte.TryParse(itemVal, b))
{
    return true; //Could be converted to Int32 and also to Byte
}
```