# Validating if input is a letter in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have a Textbox elements that I want to accept only byte values. Note that I'm pretty new to c#, so sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

so I have this piece of code

```
  if (!byte.TryParse(last, out num) && last.Length > 1)
        {

            System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();
            zBox.Text = zBox.Text.Remove(last.Length - 1);

        }
```

So, what I want is for users to enter only byte values there, and anything else than numbers to be ignored (deleted and sound played indicating wrong input). The piece of code that is there achieves that with the problem of the first entered value which can be a letter. If I don't use .length > 1 than I get an expection.

What would be the best way to validate if the entered value is a byte type?

Comment: Would this be something of your help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386434/gettype-and-typeof-in-c-sharp

Comment: Also somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268552/how-do-i-get-a-textbox-to-only-accept-numeric-input-in-wpf

Comment: You require deleting an already entered character - you should consider moving your validation to happen before the value is actually changed.

Comment: @user6144226 I was trying to achieve that, but I was not sure how to. Any pointers?

Comment: See my answer. The pointer is to handle the PreviewTextInput event and set the Cancel property of the TextCompositionEventArgs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `PreviewTextInput` event:

```
private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
    string s = tb.Text + e.Text;
    byte b;
    if (!byte.TryParse(s, out b))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        //play sound
        System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();
    }
}
```

You may also want to handle the paste command:

[Paste Event in a WPF TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061475/paste-event-in-a-wpf-textbox)

Comment: Hi. Sorry I just got to check this. This works great. I understand that this is better practice, so I fully accept this solution. It was not a direct solution to the problem, but rather an improvement and therefore I find it. In the answer below Keyur Patel solution is what I originally wanted, so both solutions are good.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you check for **both** conditions in your `if` statement, thus regardless of whether the first letter is byte or not, the checking will NOT succeed. Try something like:

```
byte num;
if (!byte.TryParse(last, out num))
{
    System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();
    if (last.Length > 1)
        zBox.Text = zBox.Text.Remove(last.Length - 1);
    else if (last.Length == 1)
        zBox.Text = "";
}
```

EDIT after reading comment: added `else if` statement

Comment: The problem here is that if the first value entered is a letter it won't delete it. I can add somethign like zBox.Text = "" prior to the second if statements. This works with teh first letter, but entering second value and typing a letter (s for example) throws an System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException. Trying to figure out why right now.

Comment: @NikolaL.Try the edited code. If entering more than 1 (incorrect) letters still gives an exception, it may be due to difference between `last` and `zBox.Text`. Lack of code before this means I cannot help you correct that.

Comment: Well in the meantime, thinking about the different if clauses I found a solution that seems to work flawlessly. Here's the final code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OuUGN2. Do you think it's okay?

Comment: @NikolaL. Your code should work fine, but I don't understand why you need to fiddle with `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength`, since `zBox.Text = zBox.Text.Remove(zBox.Text.Length - 1);` automatically moves the Caret when it removes the last letter/number.

Comment: Because Remove puts the cursor at the beginning of the entry for some reason. I didn't investigate further why does it do this, Therefore I did the SelectionStart and SelectionLength to get the cursor at the end.

Comment: @NikolaL. Try replacing those 2 lines with `zBox.CaretIndex = zBox.Text.Length;` and check if it works.

Comment: this works well. Sorry I'm pretty lacking in the reading of different properties of different objects. So, CaretIndex sets the blinking text cursor to the number representing the string count from 0 to x? Thanks :-)

Comment: Yes, x being the length.